# I have this array of objects in which I am trying to find how can I only get just the item so I would have the code and desc?

Tags: javascript

I get this piece of data back (from Fusejs) and I want to display the content within item, but using array.item just gives me undefined. How can I get just item without refIndex to display on a table?

```
array = [
    {
      item: {
        code: '25',
        description: 'code 25 desc',
      },
      refIndex: 0,
    },
    {
      item: {
        code: '26',
        description:
          'code 26 desc',
      },
      refIndex: 30,
    },
    {
      item: {
        code: '32',
        description: 'code 32 desc',
      },
      refIndex: 72,
    },
    {
      item: {
        code: '33',
        description: 'code 33 desc',
      },
      refIndex: 98,
    }
]
```

Comment: Which item exactly?

Comment: I want to get each of the items to display on a table

Comment: `array.map(element => element.item)`

Answer (score -3):

You will get data in this format, so you can easily use that map function on table and display everything what you want. If you don't want refindex just delete that value from .map

[image]

```
 array = [
    {
      item: {
        code: '25',
        description: 'code 25 desc',
      },
      refIndex: 0,
    },
    {
      item: {
        code: '26',
        description:
          'code 26 desc',
      },
      refIndex: 30,
    },
    {
      item: {
        code: '32',
        description: 'code 32 desc',
      },
      refIndex: 72,
    },
    {
      item: {
        code: '33',
        description: 'code 33 desc',
      },
      refIndex: 98,
    }
]


console.log(array.map((item, index) => {
    return {
        ...item.item,
        refIndex: item.refIndex
    }
}))
```